# Redirect to action based on role not working. Maybe routing needed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following controller

```
public class GlobalAdminController : Controller
{
    // GET: GlobalAdmin
    [AuthorizeUser(Roles = "admin")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And the home controller which is the main landing page for the app

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if(User.IsInRole("admin"))
    {
        RedirectToAction("Index", "GlobalAdmin");
    }
    return View();
}
```

The redirect to action is executed in the debugger
However the index action itself is not being executed on the global admin

I wonder if there is a better way to do this? maybe throught routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `return` to provide the redirect informations (`url`) to the browser. And the browser will redirect to the new location.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if(User.IsInRole("admin"))
    {
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "GlobalAdmin");
    }
    return View();
}
```

---

The point of the routes is to provide a way to access the actions from controller. Instead of accesing `GlobalAdmin/Index` you use the route to provide another way like `admin/index`

```
routes.MapRoute( 
     name: "Default", 
     url: "admin/{action}/{id}", 
     defaults: new { controller = "GlobalAdmin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } ); 

routes.MapRoute( 
     name: "Default", 
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

Comment: is it possible also using RouteConfig.cs? for example can the defaults be different depending on the role?  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: @EstebanV I don't think that will help to something. Actions from same controller won't behave different based on roles. If it does, maybe you want to split the controller.